# Remove multiline text with special chars from all files in a folder

Tags: terminal, osx

I have multi-line text with special characters (`i.e. //*(): etc`) looking like following in multiple files in a folder that I'm trying to remove. Tried all different solutions using `sed` and `awk` but none of them seem to like `//`.

```
// Some text with (something else) and a clack 6*5. 
// Rest on the next line with some more  
// etc. http://website.com/helloworld.php 
// and just another line.
```

All I need is to search and get rid of this text from all of the files in `data` folder.

Comment: Can you explain what part of the example you want to delete and which, if any, you want to keep?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to handle the `//` sequence using `sed`

1. backslash-escape each `/` instance

   ```
   sed '/^\/\//d' file
   ```
2. place the `/` inside a `[...]` character list

   ```
   sed  '/^[/]\{2\}/d' file
   ```

   or (with GNU sed)

   ```
   sed -r /^[/]{2}/d' file
   ```
3. change the regex delimiter to some other character, so that the `//` sequence is treated literally

   ```
    sed '\%^//%d' file
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Here's 3 methods.

1. Using gcc

   Using `gcc` you can utilize it as a preprocessor to remove the comments from a C/C++ files.

   #### Example

   ```
   $ cat test.c 
   #define foo bar
   foo foo foo
   #ifdef foo
   #undef foo
   #define foo baz
   #endif
   foo foo

   // Some text with (something else) and a clack 6*5. 
   // Rest on the next line with some more  
   // etc. http://website.com/helloworld.php 
   // and just another line.
   ```

   To remove the comments:

   ```
   $ gcc -fpreprocessed -dD -E test.c
   # 1 "test.c"
   #define foo bar
   foo foo foo
   #ifdef foo
   #undef foo
   #define foo baz
   #endif
   foo foo
   ```

   This can be adapted using `find . -iname "*.c"` to find all your `.c` files and  run the above on them, would be one approach.
2. Using `stripcmt`

   There's a tool called [stripcmt](http://www.bdc.cx/software/stripcmt/) (i.e. strip comment) that you can use to do what you want.
3. Using Perl

   You could also use this Perl CPAN module to remove comments, with a custom script. The CPAN module is called: [Regexp::Common::comment](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Regexp-Common/lib/Regexp/Common/comment.pm). There are examples on how to do this on the CPAN page.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just use `grep`:

```
grep -v // file
```

The `-v` prints lines not matching the pattern given.

Or `perl`:

```
perl -ne 'print unless m#^//#;' file
```

or

```
perl -ne 'next if m#^//#; print' file
```